# Procedure for Sending Mails to Customers from the DB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a procedure for sending emails to customers once the data loaded by them has been processed using the inbuilt procedure for sending mails. It takes the recipient of the mail,the subject and the message as input parameters.

I have to create another procedure for taking the input parameters from 2 different tables. I want to do something like the below mentioned :

To:  Email of user loaded the data thru portal.

Subject : Your application “&APP_Name” has been Published.

Message : Your application “&APP_Name”  has been Published. Please visit the link : XXXXXXXXXX

I have to get the recipient and app_name from two different tables? What is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Just select the values you need.

```
DECLARE
  v_r   VARCHAR2(100);
  v_app VARCHAR2(100);

  PROCEDURE email(p_receipent IN VARCHAR2, p_app_name IN VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('send to:' || p_receipent || ' subject:' || p_app_name || ' message: ' || p_app_name);
  END;
BEGIN
  SELECT 'demo@mydemo.so' INTO v_r FROM dual; --table1
  SELECT 'app1' INTO v_app FROM dual; --table2;

  email(v_r, v_app);
END;
```